# Python sqlite3 conn.commit() not saving data to the db file

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Here's my code

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('arbitrary.db')
c = conn.cursor()
data = ['sampletext',42]

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1(link TEXT,story_id INTEGER)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO t1 (link, story_id) VALUES (?,?)", data)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

It runs without error and doesn't throw any parsing errors, but once the script closes and I go to open the db file, It's still empty. am I making a mistake somewhere?

Appreciate the help in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same database file as your script is using?

Comment: I don't have a database file yet, and am looking to create a simple one using a python script. This script does create the file named "arbitrary.db", but the only string that the file contains when I open it is "SQlite format 3"

Comment: Have you tried opening the db using sqlite3 command? What is the output of `.ta`?

Comment: tfw I was actually just dumb and didn't realize that opening the db file in plain text doesn't show its contents. I opened the db file in a database viewer, and it turns out all the inserts I had done were there. (the filesize being 8kb was a giveaway too). It works :P